# Loading gif overlap

Tags: html, css

im currently in need of some help regarding this issue. Id like the loading gif to be placed above the drop down.

Here is the CSS for the dropdown and loading gif.

dropdown

```
.form-horizontal .control-group {

  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

here is the code for the loading image

```
.uiGridLoading,
.uiOtherLoading
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 11px;
    right: 11px;
    left: 11px;
    top: 53px;
    background: #ffffff;
    /*z-index: 900;*/
}

.uiOtherLoading
{
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;

}

div.uiGridLoading-outer,
div.uiOtherLoading-outer
{
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.uiGridLoading-inner,
div.uiOtherLoading-inner
{
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

span.uiGridLoading-text,
span.uiOtherLoading-text
{
    text-align: center;
    background: url('/img/progress.gif') top center no-repeat;
    padding-top: 47px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #666666;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 32px;



}
```

[As you can see the gif loading image is behind the drop down. I know z-index is not the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKywS.png)

Comment: I'd say `z-index` *is* the problem

Comment: ive just tried changing it so that its above the drop down and the problem still occurs

Comment: On chorme. Open the inpect element. select the dropdown that is overlaping the loading gif. on the right tab section. Click the tab named Computed and check and see what the z-index is there. increment that value by one and set it on the loading gif. Try and let me know. Also if you can put your code to mimic your problem in a fiddle that will help alot in finding a solution fast.